# Why is a euphemism regarded as poor writing by some source?

Tags: writing

Reading [this](http://www.ragan.com/Main/Articles/10_careless_writing_mistakes_and_how_to_avoid_them_46385.aspx) article about careless writing I couldn't understand the item #7:

> 7. Using euphemisms: “He passed away last year” instead of “He died last year.”

What is the reason behind this advice?

According to Alvin's comment:

> Same with the assertion that it is wrong to say "passed away" instead of "died". I consider the former more subtle, respectful and more appropriate when used for an older or senior person for example.

the use of the euphemism wouldn't be quite wrong.

So what would be your advice, using a euphemism or being blunt, or the opinions are divided and the question is opinion-based?

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid this is opinion-based. I don't agree with #3 and as for #4 *irregardless* is a word *irregardless* of what Alvin say.

Comment: I don't even agree that *pass away* is a euphemism. It's a phrasal verb meaning *to die*, *to give up the ghost*, *to expire*, etc. (I can hear the [Dead Parrot sketch](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4vuW6tQ0218) about to be referenced.)

Comment: Most people I know say and write ***a** euphemism,* since the beginning sound is not a vowel but a y-; compare *a Yankee*. But there may be some variety expressed regarding this point

Comment: Don't read anonymous internet articles on writing: a third of what they say is wrong, a third is exaggerated, and the last third is self-evident. Instead, emulate the work of writers whom you admire and who sign their names. Apply this advice to this comment as well.

Comment: Euphemism can be overused or out of place. I think the advice should say, "Using euphemisms _when it would be better to be more direct_."

Comment: In support of the advice not to (over)use euphemisms in your writing: they have a tendency to become clichés.

Answer (score 2):

The use of euphemisms is very tricky. The question is always, when you run across one, "So why can't you say what you mean?". The answer, of course, is that some subjects are considered offensive. What makes it tricky is that not everyone agrees as to which subjects are offensive. The two standards are death and sex, and even these do not follow universal rules.

Back in the 1950's, British society was considerably stirred up by the distinction between "u" and "non-u" (upper-class vs non-upper-class) vocabulary. One notable feature of the differences was that "u" vocabulary was often more blunt than "non-u", in defiance of the expectation that the upper classes were more refined in their speech than the lower classes. Dead vs passed away and graveyard vs cemetery are examples. The question of what is offensive is very much a social, especially class, issue.

And, of course, it's easy to get carried away with euphemisms. Consider the "Dead Parrot Sketch" from Monty Python. For those not familiar with it (it's on YouTube), an unhappy customer brings a parrot back to a pet shop - his complaint is that the store sold him a dead parrot. The owner explains that the parrot isn't dead, "e's just resting", and being a Norwegian Blue, is "pining for the fjords". Eventually the customer loses his temper:

'E's not pinin'! 'E's passed on! This parrot is no more! He has ceased to be! 'E's expired and gone to meet 'is maker!
'E's a stiff! Bereft of life, 'e rests in peace! If you hadn't nailed 'im to the perch 'e'd be pushing up the daisies!
 'Is metabolic processes are now 'istory! 'E's off the twig!
 'E's kicked the bucket, 'e's shuffled off 'is mortal coil, run down the curtain and joined the bleedin' choir invisible!!
THIS IS AN EX-PARROT!!

This, of course, is only a small subset of the available euphemisms. This site http://dying.about.com/od/Funeral_Memorial_Planning/a/101-Euphemisms-For-Dead-Death-Or-Dying.htm provides 101 such euphemisms, along with Voltaire's remark that "One great use of words is to hide our thoughts."

And if you think death is bad, sex (in most Western societies) is worse. How much worse, you ask? Well, this site http://www.mantality.co.za/blog/wanking-euphemism.html lists 500 euphemisms for "masturbation". "Choking the chicken" and "dating Rosie Palm and her five sisters" is just the beginning.

Pregnancy was pretty much taboo in the US (at least, talking about it was) from the Victorian era to roughly the '60s. So terms like "enceinte" (from the French), "in a family way", "expecting", and a whole slew of others was used. This attitude has generally passed away (See? It's easy to do.), although most of the euphemisms have remained, but are used purely for the sake of variety and humor.

So, in general euphemisms should be avoided, since by their nature they are designed to avoid actually talking about the subject under discussion. Unless you are determined to avoid bringing up subjects that someone might find offensive. Even then, you might keep in mind the story (almost certainly false) about Winston Churchill, who was visiting in the US, and made the mistake of referring to a breast of chicken. He was corrected by his hostess, who informed Churchill that in America, "white meat" and "dark meat" were the preferred terms. The next day he sent the hostess a corsage with a note that asked "Madam, I would be honoured if you would pin this to your white meat in remembrance of me."

Comment: -1 Because there is a difference between slang and euphemism.

Answer (score -1):

There are several factors that can come into play when deciding which one you want to use. Who is the public of the text you're writing? Is it in a formal or informal setting? What is the purpose of your text?

For example, in an official letter you would sooner say *passed away*, but when talking to a friend who was not close to the victim, you could just as well say *died*.

So it all depends on context, and perhaps also your speaking/writing style. Some writers may be more direct while others prefer being indirect. Euphemisms cannot really be **wrong**, but it would for example be rather weird to say to your friends in a bar that you found a film *rather unpleasant to watch* instead of saying that you *didn't like the film at all*.

Comment: *Finding something rather unpleasant to watch* is not a euphemism.